# Crontab does not run my python script usi.py

Tags: python, bash, cron, debian-jessie

I checked a lot posts with the same title, but I can't get my python running via cron.
I have several cron scripts already, which execute well, but not python.

Crontab runs as root.

I added following lines to crontab:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

I have this line for the execution in crontab:

```
* * * * *  cd /var/www/usi/; /usr/local/bin/python3.6 /var/www/usi/usi.py
```

I tried a lot of variations:

- added sudo in front of it to run as a different user
- added bash to the line
- executed the user profile before etc etc.

No results.
No errors in system log.

Any ideas?

Using Debian8

Comment: Try using `&&` instead of semicolon for separation - that way if changing directory fails you'll at least get a proper error in your crontab log.

Comment: Which OS and version do you use? Which file contains your crontab?

Comment: Changed it.
Nothing wrong in syslog.

I am using: Debian 8. Crontab under  /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root

Comment: Add usi.py to your question.

Comment: Is is just this script, or does it fail to run any python program?  Did you try a simple "Hello world"?

Comment: Good point. From command line it works. Using cron I get nothing. Syslog shows no errors, but not any output from the python script.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error while putting the cron task into a separate shell script. I executed the script via cron and got an error. Simple typo. Did now saw any error before in syslog. :-(

It executes well with this in crontab now:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin

* * * * *  cd /var/www/usi/ && /usr/local/bin/python3.6 /var/www/usi/usi.py
```